# why visual studio 2013 creates buggy c# source inside obj directory while compiling?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, visual-studio-2013

I am converting a silverlight project to WPF in c# using visual studio 2013 . for some codes it creates some c# source codes inside obj folder,when i build the project and what is worse is they have bugs and i have no access to them to debug .
the bugs prevents me from successful compilation.here is the error:

```
Error   2   The type name 'IComponentConnector' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Windows.Markup'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

what are they?where they come from and how to debug them?

Comment: Ignore them. Any 'bugs' in this code would only come from your actual code.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the error? Mostly, they're generated from the XAML files (basically they contain all the placeholder code that allows you to reference a XAML object in the code-behind file). Also, you can try to delete all the `obj` folders, to be sure they're cleanly re-generated